# Warning in the logs of Postfix: "restriction NNN ignored: no SASL support". But it does have SASL support

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

I have postfix + dovecot + pgsql. All has been working. Recently I've changed something in the config to combat spam. Now I see this in the logs:

```
localhost postfix/smtpd[2299]: warning: restriction `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch' ignored: no SASL support 

localhost postfix/smtpd[2299]: warning: restriction `reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch' ignored: no SASL support 

localhost postfix/smtpd[2299]: warning: restriction `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch' ignored: no SASL support 

localhost postfix/smtpd[2299]: warning: restriction `reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch' ignored: no SASL support
```

But!

```
$ postconf -a
cyrus
dovecot
```

And

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/postfix | grep sasl
    libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f9508e75000)
```

If I remember correctly, I installed postfix via "pacman".

Why the warning and how to fix it?

upd1:

```
sudo postconf | grep -i smtpd_sasl

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks =
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_service = smtp
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

upd2:

in `master.cf` I've found this:

```
 smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
       -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
```

Can this be the reason?

upd3:

also:

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

Comment: But are they enabled?  Please add the contents of `postconf | grep -i smtpd_sasl`.  In my case, with dovecot, I have these 3 values specifically set:
`smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
`

Comment: Sasl is a little bit funny on Postfix, you need to use saslauthd and configure them to work together. Sometimes surprising error messages are possible, but *it can be done*. A strace would be highly useful.

Comment: @StephenHarris see my update

Comment: @peterh I don't understand

Comment: Is the postfix user in the sasl group? ... or said another way... The postfix user needs to be able to access the dovecot sasl unix socket... [see here](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot)

Comment: And... looking again at the error... perhaps you've forgotten to setup your sender maps... [error](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) ... [map setup](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps)

Comment: @RubberStamp see my update#2

Comment: Settings, settings, everywhere... A good place to start is checking if the sasl socket exists... My setup is as follows: **1** point to `saslauthd` via `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` ... **2** authenticate via my imap server using `rimap` option in `/etc/default/saslauthd` ... **3** since my `postfix` is running chroot, my sasl socket is located at `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux` ... and the postfix user is in the sasl group.  **4** my usernames and hashed passwords are stored in a psql db and accessed via my courier imap server.

Comment: @RubberStamp elaborate on that in your answer

Comment: `ls /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` -- file doesn't exist

Comment: @RubberStamp I hadn't heard of that, not usually tutorials describe that

Comment: @RubberStamp up.

Comment: Answer is half done... tomorrow... I noticed I answered an earlier one of your `postfix` questions.  Are these two questions related?  Did my last answer create problems and make for a new question? ... Hopefully not.

Comment: @RubberStamp probably not

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by assuming that in your case you send and receive mail using the same IP address (what's termed a smart host).

In this scenario mail will usually be submitted for sending by yourself on port 587 but received on port 25.

Why is this important?  Because in this configuration postfix will use the port to identify how to treat the connection.

Lets look at some real logs from my SMTP server - the first from a connection on port 25

```
Nov 26 07:33:45 box postfix/smtpd[128819]: connect from host86-157-106-5.range86-157.btcentralplus.com[86.157.106.5]
Nov 26 07:35:01 box postfix/smtpd[128819]: warning: restriction `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch' ignored: no SASL support
Nov 26 07:35:02 box postfix/smtpd[128819]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from host86-157-106-5.range86-157.btcentralplus.com[86.157.106.5]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [86.157.106.5] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/86.157.106.5; from=<myaddress@timothydutton.co.uk> to=<myaddressn@blueyonder.co.uk> proto=ESMTP helo=<desktop>
Nov 26 07:35:13 box postfix/smtpd[128819]: disconnect from host86-157-106-5.range86-157.btcentralplus.com[86.157.106.5] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

Now from a connection on the same IP address using port 587

```
Nov 26 07:40:53 box postfix/smtpd[130170]: disconnect from unknown[185.218.234.97] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=4/5
Nov 26 07:43:12 box postfix/submission/smtpd[130244]: connect from host86-157-106-5.range86-157.btcentralplus.com[86.157.106.5]
Nov 26 07:43:31 box postfix/submission/smtpd[130244]: warning: host86-157-106-5.range86-157.btcentralplus.com[86.157.106.5]: SASL plain authentication failed:
Nov 26 07:43:36 box postfix/submission/smtpd[130244]: disconnect from host86-157-106-5.range86-157.btcentralplus.com[86.157.106.5] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=4/5
```

For each connection I used the same AUTH PLAIN command.
AUTH PLAIN

So what's going on.

Lets start by saying that in an ideal scenario the client will send AUTH PLAIN on it's own and then receive the response 334 from the server - assuming that the authentication method is supported.  Then the client will send the authentication info.

However AUTH PLAIN does allow you to send the whole lot in one command by adding the authentication string to the same line.  In which case it will forgo the 334 line and just jump straight in with the authentication.

```
250 SMTPUTF8
ehlo desktop
250-box.timothydutton.co.uk
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 134217728
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
auth plain <base64 string with email address and wrong password>
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
closed
```

The above was actually taken from the second connection attempt on port 587

However because port 25 is used for receiving mail.  SASL is not used.  What happens is that the server should be configured that all connections on port 25 will only accept rcpt: to addresses belonging to that server.  This stops the server from being used as an open relay.

So what's happening is the server is processing the additional info in the AUTH PLAIN command and saying, well it's wrong, but it doesn't matter as I don't actually use authentication on this port.

We see from the response in the first example that the server does have other defences in play.

Note:  I own the server used to show the connection examples.